# Mapping an array present inside an object working only when given in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Reactjs.

I wanted to render an array present inside an object.

```
state = {
   obj: { 
           name: abhishek,
           age: 23,
           characterList: ['a','b','c','d']
        }
}
```

I found out that in order to render the characterList I had to wrap it in a conditional statement.

And I'm not able to figure out the reason.

Incorrect:

```
render(){
return(
         <>
             {
                 this.state.obj.characterList.map((character, i) => {
                      return(
                          <h1>{character}</h1>
                      )
                 })
             }
         </>
      )
```

This gives error - 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

But if given in conditional statement like this -

Correct:

```
render(){
return(
         <>
             { this.state.obj.characterList ? 
               (
                   this.state.obj.characterList.map((character, i) => {
                        return(
                            <h1>{character}</h1>
                        )
                   })
               ) : null
             }
         </>
      )
```

Original Code: which is giving error (cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

```
export default (props) => {
  const [FAQs, setFAQs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/FAQs/getFAQs");
    setFAQs(res.data);
    console.log(res.data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="faqs-wapper">
        <div className="faqs-heading">
          <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
          <h2>{FAQs.category}</h2> //This works fine.
        </div>
        { 
            FAQs.FAQList.map((QA,i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <p>{QA.question}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

res.data coming is:

```
{
   category: "Getting Started",
   FAQList: [
                {
                   question: "is two factor authentication mandatory?",
                   answer: "Clients are required to perform 2FA."
                },
                {
                   question: "how long does transfer take?",
                   answer: "Depends on amount."
                },
            ]
}
```

Original Code: which is working when given in conditional statement

```
export default (props) => {
  const [FAQs, setFAQs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/FAQs/getFAQs");
    setFAQs(res.data[0]);
    console.log(res.data[0]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="faqs-wapper">
        <div className="faqs-heading">
          <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
          <h2>{FAQs.category}</h2> //This works fine.
        </div>
        { FAQs.FAQList ?
            FAQs.FAQList.map((QA,i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <p>{QA.question}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            }) : null
        }
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is that your initial state? where do you change it? also, notice that nothing is returned from the map function you provided.

Comment: I agree the way you access the variable is correct. Your state is corrupted somehow, and `this.state.obj.characterList` is `undefined`. That is why `null` is returned in your correct code sample

Comment: Probably at first render you have empty state or it doesn't contain that particular array

Comment: The state has been set correctly inside constructor. 
I am able to access everything present inside the object inside render function except any array present inside the object. 

It is only when I use conditional statement that i'm able to render the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing FAQs to be an empty array in your `useState`. After your api request is complete your `setFAQs` method appears to set `FAQs` as an object with `FAQList` as a key on the FAQs object. Change `setFAQs(res.data)` to `setFAQs(res.data.FAQList)` and change your map to `FAQs.map` from `FAQs.FAQList.map`

Your original error is happening because the component is rendered before the api request is complete and `FAQs.FAQList` is undefined. You are trying to look up a property on an undefined value here: `FAQs.FAQList.map` which throws a type error.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am returning from map function. I am able to access name and age in render function, but not any kind of list. 

Only when i use conditional statement, I'm able to access lists present inside the state object. Rest there is no difference in code.

Comment: I have edited the question and put original code. Please check @Dylance